# Hibernate : classpath resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I have a Maven project using Spring and Hibernate. When I launch it in Eclipse using Debug As > Java Application, it works great. But once I exported it as a runnable .jar file, it gives me this error :

```
class path resource [com/xxx/file.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

But when I open the .jar file, the file is located under /resources/com/xxx.file.hbm.xml. What did I do wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: It could be some sort of permissions issue...

Comment: No, I'm betting that you're missing the leading "resource/" in your code where you ask for it from the classpath.  Or the manifest doesn't include it.

Comment: If you open the jar and there is a resources folder there is something wrong, there shouldn't be a resources folder. You shouldn't use the export function of eclipse to create a jar, that is what you should use maven for.

Comment: @M. Deinum : I think you're right, I shouldn't use the export function to create a jar. But I did not manage to generate the jar with maven. That said, it's the procedure my boss used with another project. In the jar of this other project there is exactly the same file located at the same position, and it works well =(

Comment: @duffymo : I ask for this file in my applicationContext.xml, located under resources/, so I guess it uses relative path.

Comment: Don't use export (again) as that exports the paths as is, unless you do some reconfiguration. But as stated you should really use maven to create the jar, if that fails fix your build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to get it to work by specifying an absolute path instead of a relative path in my applicationcontext.xml file. In concrete terms, I changed "com/xxx/file.hbm.xml" to "/resources/com/xxx/file.hbm/xml". Thanks to duffymo for leading me to the right way.